# jQuery.ajax returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: ajax, jquery

This works fine:

```
jQuery('#my_get_related_keywords').click(function() {
    if (jQuery('#my_keyword').val() == '') return false;
        jQuery.getJSON("http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/"
        +jQuery('#my_keyword').val()+"?"
        +"appid=myAppID"
        +"&lang=en"
        +"&format=json"
        +"&count=50"
        +"&view=keyterms"
        +"&callback=?",
        function (data) {//do something}
```

This returns 400 Bad Request (Just a reformulation of the above jQuery using .ajax to support error handling).

```
jQuery('#my_get_related_keywords').click(function()
    {
    if (jQuery('#my_keyword').val() == '') return false; 
    jQuery('#my_loader').show();
    jQuery.ajax(
        {
        url: "http://boss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web/v1/"
        +jQuery('#my_keyword').val()+"?"
        +"appid=myAppID"
        +"&lang=en"
        +"&format=json"
        +"&count=50"
        +"&view=keyterms"
        +"&callback=?", 
        success: function(data)
            {//do something}
```

Comment: do you have to add method (post or get) somewhere?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you just need to add 2 more options (`contentType` and `dataType`):

```
$('#my_get_related_keywords').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "HERE PUT THE PATH OF YOUR SERVICE OR PAGE",
            data: '{"HERE YOU CAN PUT DATA TO PASS AT THE SERVICE"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // this
            dataType: "json", // and this
            success: function (msg) {
               //do something
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                //do something else
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your ajax call:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json"
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. @Toro just beat you to it :)

Answer (score 7):

Late answer, but I figured it's worth keeping this updated.  Expanding on Andrea Turri answer to reflect updated jQuery API and .success/.error deprecated methods.

As of jQuery 1.8.* the preferred way of doing this is to use .done() and .fail(). [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

e.g.

```
$('#my_get_related_keywords').click(function() {

    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "HERE PUT THE PATH OF YOUR SERVICE OR PAGE",
        data: '{"HERE YOU CAN PUT DATA TO PASS AT THE SERVICE"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"});

    //When the request successfully finished, execute passed in function
    ajaxRequest.done(function(msg){
           //do something
    });

    //When the request failed, execute the passed in function
    ajaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR, status){
        //do something else
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure and use 'get' or 'post' consistantly with your $.ajax call  for example.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
```

must be met with

> app.get('/', function(req, res) {

===============
and for post

> ```
> $.ajax({
>     type: 'post',
> ```

must be met with

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the 400 Bad Request error, even after setting:

```
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json"
```

The issue was with the type of a property passed in the json object, for the `data` property in the ajax request object. 
To figure out the issue, I added an error handler and then logged the error to the console. Console log will clearly show validation errors for the properties if any.

This was my initial code:

```
var data = {
    "TestId": testId,
    "PlayerId": parseInt(playerId),
    "Result": result
};

var url = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + "/api/tests"
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data), // issue with a property type in the data object
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e); // logging the error object to console
    },
    success: function () {
        console.log('Success saving test result');
    }
});
```

Now after making the request, I checked the console tab in the browser development tool.
It looked like this:
[image]

`responseJSON.errors[0]` clearly shows a validation error: *The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.TestId*, which means I have to convert `TestId` to a string in the data object, before making the request.

Changing the data object creation like below fixed the issue for me:

```
var data = {
        "TestId": String(testId), //converting testId to a string
        "PlayerId": parseInt(playerId),
        "Result": result
};
```

I assume other possible errors could also be identified by logging and inspecting the error object.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AJAX` call is not completed with the following two `params`.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json"
```

- `contentType` is the type of data you're sending
- `dataType` is what you're expecting back from the server

In addition try to use `JSON.stringify()` method. It is used to turn a `javascript` object into `json` string.