# 400 bad request error when using jQuery.post

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to Rails and is trying jQuery.post to post a form using ajax and show the results.

But I'm only getting this in my console when I click submit:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/main/newStuff 400 (Bad Request)
```

I am looking at the example at the bottom of [this jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

Here is my ajax code:

```
$( "#new_stuff_form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get some values from elements on the page:
    var $form = $( this ),
        title = $form.find( "#new_stuff_title" ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( "action" );

    // Send the data using post
    var posting = $.post( url, { title: title } );

    posting.done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    posting.fail(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
def createStuff
    @stuff = Stuff.new(stuff_params)
    @stuff.save
    render json: {status: "ok"}
end

private
def stuff_params
    params.require(:stuff).permit(:title, :due_date)
end
```

And here is my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @stuff, url: stuff_create_path, html: {id: "new_stuff_form",class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"} do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="new_stuff_title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.input_field :title, class: 'form-control', id: 'new_stuff_title' %>
    </div>
</div>
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

Here is my route setting:

```
post 'main/newStuff' => 'main#createStuff', as: :stuff_create
```

P.S. it works when I am not using ajax so I think the controller and the view is ok.

Comment: can you set this `console.log` url, and title variable to make sure these are right?

Comment: Hi @MohamedYakot, yes I added console.log(url) and console.log(title) to my code and the outputs are "/main/newStuff" and the correct string I type in to the form for "title".

Comment: I see your action called `createStuff`, not `newStuff`, do you forget to change it ?, if no please type `newStuff` action

Comment: but my route setting is: `post 'main/newStuff' => 'main#createStuff', as: :stuff_create`

Comment: is there any problem?

Comment: No, I don't notice that :), you're right

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
$.post( url, { title: title }, function() {
   alert( "success" );
 })
 .done(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
 })
 .fail(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
 }), dataType: "json" );
```

I think you need to add your `dataType`, see answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156991/jquery-ajax-returns-400-bad-request).