# Upload a simple file and input to Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I'm using Spring MVC. I want to upload a file but my attempts are not working. This is my last attempt.
**I debugged and I correctly get the file object and the form serialized in ajax.**

I'm getting this so obviously I'm doing something bad.

> POST http://localhost:8080/upload/testCase 400 (Bad Request)

**How do I get the form data and file on the Controller?**

HTML:

```
     <input id="testName" class="form-control" name="testName" placeholder="Insert a name for the test case">
     <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" class="hide"/>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var file = new FormData();
$('#fileUpload').change(function () {
    file.append('file',$('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]);
    console.log($('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]);
});

$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#creationForm').serialize();
    console.log(data + file);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/upload/testCase',
        data: {data: data, file: file},
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Controller Java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/testCase" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadTestCase(@RequestParam("data") String data, @RequestParam("file") File file ) {
    //TestCases.upload(file);
    System.out.println(data + file);
    return "";
}
```

BackEnd

```
public static void upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {

    //1. get the files from the request object
    Iterator<String> itr =  request.getFileNames();

    MultipartFile mpf = request.getFile(itr.next());
    System.out.println(mpf.getOriginalFilename() +" uploaded!");

}
```

Comment: any help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery.ajax returns 400 Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156991/jquery-ajax-returns-400-bad-request)

Comment: Hi Try this way                                                                 
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/testCase" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadTestCase(@RequestParam("data") String data, @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file) {
    //TestCases.upload(file);
    System.out.println(data + file);
    return "";
}